How to plan an Microsoft Booking's appointment without duplicate customer?
Ciao,
I am working on .ASP.NET Core 8.0 project for appointment management. Appointment are stored on Microsoft Booking Calendar and I'm using API Graph for calendar management (package Microsoft.Graph 5.4).
My appointment creation flow consist on:

To make the first step, I get the customers using Microsoft Graph API Get bookingCustomer:
var customers = await graphClient.Solutions.BookingBusinesses[bookingBusinessId].Customers.GetAsync();

To make the second step, I create the appointment using Microsoft Graph Create bookingAppointment:
var customersBookingAppointment = customers
    .Select(x => (BookingCustomerInformationBase)new BookingCustomerInformation
    {
        CustomerId = x.Id,
        EmailAddress = x.EmailAddress,
        Name = x.DisplayName
    })
    .ToList();
    
var bookingAppointment = new BookingAppointment()
{
    OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.bookingAppointment",
    CustomerTimeZone = timeZone,
    SmsNotificationsEnabled = false,
    ServiceId = service?.Id,
    StartDateTime = startAppointment,
    Duration = durationAppointment,
    EndDateTime = endAppointment,
    ServiceNotes = note,
    Customers = customersBookingAppointment,
    StaffMemberIds = staffs
};

var result = await graphClient.Solutions.BookingBusinesses[BookingBusinessId].Appointments.PostAsync(bookingAppointment);

The problem is that each time I plan an appointment, customers on Microsoft Booking are recreated.
I noticed that there are difference between documentation and the response obtained: API Get bookingCustomer's documentation show customer ids as a GUID but I obtain a string base64.
How can I resolve this problem?
Thank you
